# php template OO encoding problem

Tags: php, oop, templates, encoding, utf-8

i'm trying to use a tempalte system in php for a website I had. anyways, everything is working ok so far, except for  the encoding, when i render the website, is not taking the utf-8...

this is my empresa.php page code:

```
<?php
require_once 'template.class.php';

$view = new View();

$view -> title  = 'Empresa';
$view -> extra_css = '';
$view -> extra_js = '';
$view -> content = '
                        <div class="tituloP">Misión:</div>
                        <p class="marginP">
                        Procesar, envasar y comercializar alimentos de alta calidad cumpliendo y mejorando los estándares conocidos para satisfacer oportuna y plenamente las necesidades y expectativas de nuestros clientes.
                        </p> 
                        <div class="tituloP">Visión:</div>
                        <p class="marginP">
                        Ser una empresa innovadora y promotora del desarrollo de productos alimenticios de alta calidad y excelente imagen para sobrepasar las expectativas de nuestros clientes. Fortalecer nuestra competitividad para igualar a las empresas líderes, manteniendo una constante presencia y abriéndonos a nuevos mercados dentro del contexto local, regional, nacional y con proyecciones al mercado internacional.
                        </p>
                        <div class="tituloP">Historia:</div>
                        <p class="marginP">
                        En sus inicios nació como una empresa  dedicada solo a la distribución de encurtidos  obtenidos de terceros, entregados a un delimitado número de clientes. A medida que fue creciendo decidió emprender en el negocio de la producción y así nacieron los productos “mel®”, que hoy son parte de la empresa llamada <b>Agroindustria®</b> la que ha expandido su negocio a la elaboración de salsas, sucedáneo de jugo de limón  y que en el año 2003 adquirió la marca <b>Mos®</b>, marca conocida en el mercado nacional por más de 50 años.
                        </p>


                        <br /><div id="allproducts"></div><br /> 
                        <div id="lineapunteada"></div>
                        <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="impresora" class="printer">imprimir</a>
                        <br />
                    ';

echo $view -> render('template.php');

?>
```

this is my class:

```
<?php
class View {
     public function render($script) {
        ob_start();
        $this->_include($script);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return (isset($this -> $key) ? $this -> $key : null);
    }

    protected function _include() {
        include func_get_arg(0);
    }
}
?>
```

andddd template.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<title>Mos | <?php echo $this -> title; ?></title>

<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php echo $this -> extra_css; ?>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script src="DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
    <script>
            DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, div');
    </script>
<![endif]--> 

<?php echo $this -> extra_js; ?>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main">  
        <div id="container_black">
            <div id="container_white">

                <div id="container_header">

                    <div id="logo_top"></div>           
                    <div id="lineas_verticales_top">
                        <div class="volver_portada"><a href="index.php">Volver a portada</a></div>
                        <div class="english_spanish"><u>Español</u> | <a href="../en/index.php" class="english_spanish">English</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav_bar_black"><div id="nav_bar_red"><div id="nav_bar_yel">

                        <ul class="menuholder"> 
                            <li class="menu_principal"><a href="#" title="Principal">Principal</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_empresa"><a href="#" title="Empresa">Empresa</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_productos"><a href="#" title="Productos">Productos</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_clientes"><a href="#" title="Clientes">Clientes</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_recetas"><a href="#" title="Recetas">Recetas</a></li> 
                            <li class="menu_contacto"><a href="#" title="Contacto">Contacto</a></li> 
                        </ul> 

                    </div></div></div>
                    <div id="topbg_degr"></div>

                </div>

                <div id="container_left">
                    <div id="conmargen_left_top"></div>
                    <div id="container_conmargen_left_middle">

                        <div class="top_title"><?php echo $this -> title; ?></div>
                        <div id="hrTitle"></div>


                        <?php echo $this -> content; ?>

                    </div>
                    <div id="conmargen_left_bottom"></div>

                    <!--[IF INDEX]
                    <div id="fono"></div>
                    <div id="dir"></div>
                    -->

                </div>

                <!--[IF INDEX]
                <div id="nav"></div>
                -->

                <div id="container_right">
                    <div id="conmargen_right_top"></div>
                    <div id="container_conmargen_right_middle">

                        <a href="#" id="recetas_poster" title="recetas"></a>


                        -->

                    </div>
                    <div id="conmargen_right_bottom"></div>
                </div>



                <br/>   

            </div> <!-- cierre del container white -->
        </div> <!-- cierre del container black -->

        <div id="footer">   
                <div class="footer_comment">
                    Agroindustria e.i.r.l. Todos los derechos reservados 2011
                </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- cierre del main -->
<br/>

</body>

</html>
```

anyways, everything seems to be working fine, but the á é í etc.. are not displaying im just getting ? mark.

Also any advice on my template system is welcome too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor you are using must save the `empresa.php` file in UTF-8 format (most likely it doesn't, but uses ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252 or s/t similiar).

Comment: i checked in the MS expression web optiones, and there is an option under format called properties, and in the tab advance, you can see the encoding option, i chose, unicode UTF8 and it works perfectly, thank you =)